# OpenLayers 3 - Zoomify - Tiles - Getting started

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, zoomify

I am new to OpenLayers and want to switch from Google Maps API.

Now I am trying to figure out how to place a big image into OpenLayers like I can do with the Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

I guess the dependance with OpenLayers is Zoomify, right?
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/zoomify.html

Now I can't find any good How To or Get Started on Zoomify.

- is there a good introduction on OpenLayers and Zoomify which I should know?
- how do I need to slice the image into tiles?
- can I name the tiles like I do for Google Maps?
- I downloaded OL3 but the examples are not working. Do I need to compile something?

Comment: OL3 is new and as such the documentation is a bit scant still, as the developers have, naturally, been working on the code. The best resource is the source code. The example above is already working, so I am not sure what your issue is. You need to setup nodejs to run the examples locally, but that is another question.

Comment: You don't need nodejs to get started. It's only to run local examples or when you want to optimize js size for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- is there a good introduction on OpenLayers and Zoomify which I should know?

The [OpenLayers 3 Quickstart](http://openlayers.org/en/master/doc/quickstart.html) and the [OpenLayers 3 workshop](http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/)

- how do I need to slice the image into tiles?

Yes, there are various possibilities using PHP, Python and Ruby. See [this blog post](http://greengaloshes.cc/2007/05/zoomifyimage-ported-to-php/) for PHP and Python links and Ruby at this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dball/zoomifier).

- can I name the tiles like I do for Google Maps?

No, Google Maps use specific tiles splitting and Zoomify don't use the same.

- I downloaded OL3 but the examples are not working. Do I need to compile something?

No, just go to https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.0.0. At the bottom, click on the v3.0.0.zip download link, unzip it. Put the directory on any webserver and open the examples directory and you will see all demos working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vips to generate Zoomify tile pyramids. There's [a post on the vips blog](http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html) explaining how to use the tool. For example:

```
vips dzsave myhugefile.tif output_directory --layout zoomify
```

will create a tile pyramid in the directory **output_directory**.

The vips pyramid creator is very fast and can build pyramids of images of any size using only a little memory.